# List and filter AWS topics in Powershell

Tags: powershell, aws-cli

I'm trying to list all the sns topics that contain `local`, in a powershell script

I've got this working (finally):

```
aws sns list-topics --query 'Topics[?contains(TopicArn, `local`)].TopicArn'
```

Now I want to replace 'local' with a variable

```
aws sns list-topics --query 'Topics[?contains(TopicArn, $prefix)].TopicArn'
```

But this doesn't work because the --query parameter expects the filter to be surrounded by back ticks.  Also, the whole query parameter needs to be surrounded by single ticks, not double quotes.

**How can I achieve this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could format the `--query` with [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.4#format-operator--f)(`-f`).

```
$ aws sns list-topics --query ('Topics[?contains(TopicArn, `{0}`)].TopicArn' -f $prefix)
```